# What is the best stable sort algorithm when my key space contains only two elements

Tags: algorithm, performance, sorting, computer-science

Alphabet contains only two numbers like

```
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

and it could be really large(at least millions)
I need to soft it by swap operations(when I do a swap I will also make same changes on adjacent data structures). Sort also must be stable.

In my case swap operation do expensive, sort algorithm also should minimize them.

O(n) additional space complexity is acceptable if it reduce number of swaps significantly.

What is the best sorting algorithm in that case?

Comment: How do you intend to use that extra space if only swaps are allowed?

Comment: May be we can store positions of the elements in the final array and that information will help us to reduce number of swaps.

Comment: Absolutely, I think it's the best compromise. O(n) time and space complexity, but only for your supporting indices array, which will only be a few megs big. Then use it to easily swap/sort the elements in-place in your other DS, still in O(n).

Comment: If the algorithm is in place and stable, then the swaps have to be adjacent used to shift data. For example, if the 1 at array[2] was swapped with the 0 at array[4], then after the swap, the 1's at array[3] and array[4] would be out of order. " The 1's could be "swapped" to a second array, and replaced by 2's. Then the order of 2's would not matter when swapping to shift all the 0's down. After than swap the 1's from the second array back to the original. You'd need to keep track of the position of the containers related to the 0's and 1's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your 0/1 array is an int[], then you can do the whole thing in linear time with no extra space:

1. replace the 0s and 1s with the final position of the corresponding element.  You can do this easily in linear time;
2. swap each element and it's corresponding number into the correct position, again in linear time; then
3. If you like, replace the positions in the 0/1 array with 0s and 1s again.  You probably counted the zeros first when you did step 1, so just fill it with that many 0s and the rest 1s

The whole thing looks like this:

```
void zeroOneSort<T>(int *keys, T *values, int len)
{
    //count zeros
    int numZeros = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<len; ++i)
    {
        if (!keys[i])
           ++numZeros;
    }

    //fill in positions
    {
        int zeroPos=0, onePos = numZeros;
        for(int i=0; i<len; ++i)
        {
            if (!keys[i])
               keys[i] = zeroPos++;
            else
               keys[i] = onePos++;
        }
    }

    //swap into place
    for(int i=0; i<len; ++i)
    {
        int target;
        while ((target=keys[i])!=i)
        {
           std::swap(keys[i],keys[target]);
           std::swap(values[i],values[target]);
        }
    }

    //fix up keys
    for(int i=0; i<numZeros; ++i)
    {
        keys[i]=0;
    }
    for(int i=numZeros; i<len; ++i)
    {
        keys[i]=1;
    }
}
```

Note that the sorting step does at most N-1 swaps, making this much faster (since you said swaps were expensive) than any of the standard sorts.

If your original keys are in a bit vector or something else that you can't replace with positions, then you can write the positions into a separate int array instead.